# Jetty (9.2.13) HTTP client with Socks4Proxy hangs

Tags: java, jetty, burp

I'm using Burp's proxy server which is running in background.
I have inserted the cacert.der into my java trust store to which my eclipse is pointing to.

Now I have the following code :
...........................................................................

```
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
httpClient.start();
Address address = new Address("127.0.0.1",8082);
Socks4Proxy socks4Proxy = new Socks4Proxy(address, true);
proxyConfiguration.getProxies().add(socks4Proxy);
Request request = httpClient.newRequest(
new URI("https://google.com"));
request.method(HttpMethod.GET);

ContentResponse contentResponse = request.send();
System.out.println(contentResponse.getContentAsString());
```

...........................................................................

The above code is giving me the following error :

Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: SOCKS4 tunnel failed with code 84
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:653)
at Get.main(Get.java:43)
...............................................................................

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this ??

Comment: Burp functions as an HTTP proxy not a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: @PortSwigger Thanks for your response. Can  you suggest me some tool where I can test HTTPS proxy or in other words , can you suggest me some way to test https proxy ?

Comment: Hi Diplankar. Most HTTP proxies - including Burp - can handle both HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: Thanks for your response @PortSwigger